# How to reset multiple label in one click of button vb net

Tags: vb.net

I created a program that when i click the button, all the Label text will be reset in Empty.

I have 31 labels, and 1 button..

When I click the button, i want that the output will be the labels are empty.

Comment: I just dont know what the code to clear all text in 31 labels in just 1 click. :) THank you!!

Comment: Did you have other labels that you don't want to clear? Are you talking about WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? Why do you tag this question with SQL?

Comment: Did you tried anything? Writing all labels by name and setting `.Text = string.Empty`? Or maybe you added all labels to the collection and you need only loop through them and reset text?

Comment: all done sir :) thank you!

Comment: @Im.Lean. if an answer solved your issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) , else you should write ur own answer.

Answer (score 0):

**First method**

Loop over label using this code:

```
For each Lbl as Label in Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()

   Lbl.Text = ""

Next
```

**Second method**

Or you have to list all labels and change `.Text` property

```
Label1.Text = ""
Label2.Text = ""
Label3.Text = ""
...
```

Comment: This will not compile with `Option Strict On`

Comment: @Fabio you're right, but Vb.net option strict is set to OFF by default. I added a note to my answer

Comment: You can simply use `Form1.Controls.OfType(Of Label)()` and inside loop `lbl.Text = ""` which satisfy both options of `Option Strict` :)

Comment: And _make sure you are not using `Option Strict On`_ is somehow bad advise - because you want get full help from compiler. That's why you should advise to use `Option Strict On`